# Best way to handle images in App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm just learning Google App Maker. I'm making a garment tracking app for our fashion business.

Say we have multiple garments and each garment can have multiple images, how could I store the URLs for these images and then display them on the garment record? I've already got the image upload working using DriveApp.

I was thinking of using an image widget, then create next/previous buttons. Or create a HTML widget and code up some sort of slider.

Both seem quite heavy. What would be the lightest way to do this, code-wise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

1. Create Image model (with at least one field - ImageURL)
2. Create one to many relation between Garment and Image models
3. Bind Image widget to current item of the Image relation

   @datasource.item.Images.item
4. Add prev/next buttons to change selected image

   @datasource.item.Images.nextItem()

   @datasource.item.Images.prevItem()

In theory, you'll be able to upload/select images using Drive Picker widget (but be sure, that you share your images with all app users).

Comment: Thanks, ended up using the Cloudinary image upload jQuery widget in my app. nearly there with it. Saving the images is proving very tricky.